# How would I make a notepad++ like Syntax Highlighting?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking to make a "Code" editor for Visual Basic.

I just wondered how I would achieve the Syntax Highlighting with most editors use.

Comment: so, vb.net or vba ? you tagged both.

Comment: duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383574/c-sharp-perfect-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd start by subclassing the [RichTextBox](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&checkda=1&ct=1362510641&rver=6.0.5276.0&wp=MCLBI&wlcxt=msdn%24msdn%24msdn&wreply=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx&lc=1033&id=254354&mkt=en-US)

RichTextBox gives you the ability to colour text, change font, etc. Your class could then implement other features like line numbers, intellisense, showing compile-time exceptions, etc...

That said, to get a *good* one, you're going to have to made a lot of changes - and most likely tie it in to a compiler or custom parser as well as (presumably) all the other stuff that goes along with a code editor.